# It is possible skip case sensitive in dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, case-sensitive

I tried:

```
d = {3:'a',2:'b'}

if 'B' in d.values():
    print 'True'
```

For me `B` is equal to `b`, but I don't want change my dictionary.

It is possible test for case insensitive matches against the values of a dictionary?

How to check if `'B'` is present in the dictionary without changing the values?

#

More complex:

```
d = {3:'A',2:'B',6:'c'}
```

Comment: You can also make a case insensitive dict: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082152/case-insensitive-dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to loop through the values:

```
if any('B' == value.upper() for value in d.itervalues()):
    print 'Yup'
```

For Python 3, replace `.itervalues()` with `.values()`. This tests the minimum number of values; no intermediary list is created, and the `any()` loop terminates the moment a match is found.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {3:'a',2:'b'}
>>> if any('B' == value.upper() for value in d.itervalues()):
...     print 'Yup'
... 
Yup
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'b' in map(str.lower, d.values()):
   ...
```

Comment: Better use `imap` and `dict.itervalues()`, as it returns an iterator.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary this is cleaner, and will work lazy on python 3. I doubt that he has a dictionary of more than 1.000.000 values so it shouldn't matter that much :)

Comment: Yes in py3.x `map` already returns an iterator, but in py2.x it'll create a list first and then it'll look for `'b'` in it. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11963711/846892

Answer (score 0):

```
if filter(lambda x:d[x] == 'B', d):
  print "B is present
else:
  print "b is not present"
```

Comment: Question is about case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
import sys

d = {3:'A',2:'B',6:'c'}
letter = (str(sys.argv[1])).lower()

if filter(lambda x : x == letter ,[x.lower() for x in d.itervalues()]):
    print "%s is present" %(letter)
else:
    print "%s is not present" %(letter)
```