# Python if-or statement short hand

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out if there's a shorter way of writing this if statement (wrote a very basic, unrealistic if statement just so it's easy to see the point.

```
  x = 3

  if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3 or x==4:

     print x

  else:

     print "nope"
```

I would like to write something along the lines of:

```
if x == or(1,2,3,4):
```

is there any way of doing that? Or do I have to write out every option?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: format your code properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you want:

```
if x in (1, 2, 3, 4):
```

Comment: I really miss this in other languages.

Comment: If you have more than a handful of values, `if x in {1, 2, 3, 4}:` (using a set) is better. But for just four of them, it won't make a difference.

Comment: And in that case, if you're using a version of Python without set literals, define the set before the `if` statement.

Comment: @kindall: Well, `set((1,2,3,4))` isn't that terrible, certainly not the most terrible thing you'll face in Python 2.3…

Comment: @abarnert: I thought set literals were much more recent than that, circa 2.7.

Comment: @Claudiu What languages doesn't have it? Most languages have an idea of "membership in a list." In Haskell, you say `if x \`elem\` [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Even in Java, you could probably do something like `if (Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).contains(x))`.

Comment: Yeah, 2.6 doesn't have set literals, they were added in 2.7.

Comment: @kindall: well, of course you can do it in some way, but it's not as neat. `x in (1, 2, 3, 4)` to me is immediately readable. `Arrays.aslist(1, 2, 3, 4).contains(x)` is not and requires an import. javascript you have to do `[1, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(x) !== -1`, not nearly as nice. the haskell one is pretty good. in C you'd have to write your own function and use arrays, it would be a mess.

Comment: In Javascript you could do `[1, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(x) + 1` to avoid the ugly `!= -1` although that is arguably even worse.  :-)

Comment: @DSM: But under what circumstances would you be able to upgrade to 2.6, but not to 2.7? When you can't use 2.7, it's because you're stuck with some old version and you have no control over it.

Comment: @abarnert: I assumed from your reference to 2.3 that you were implying that to go back to a time when set literals weren't available, you had to go to 2.3, which was so far back that their absence was the least of your concerns.  Am I missing something obvious, like usual?

Comment: @Claudiu Yeah, Java is known for its verbosity and it shows there as well. On the other hand, one can argue that it's neater in the sense that it uses only library functions, and no special syntax. The two things required are a way to write literal lists and a function to tell if  an element is a member of said list. Most languages have both of those, even though some are pretty wordy about it (like Java.) C is an exception, of course, although it would maybe be possible to hack it in with a macro...

Comment: @kqr: i guess in terms of neatness it's ultimately a matter of personal preference. I like simple syntax that is easy to grok. I prefer syntax over function calls, so long as all the syntax is readable. Python's one of my favorites in this respect.

Comment: One thing I do appreciate about Python is how its syntax puts the thing you're looking for first, rather than putting the container first. When you're looking for a needle in a haystack, you're probably more invested in the needle than in the haystack...

Comment: @DSM: I'm implying that if you don't have set literals, you have some unspecified old version of Python, and it's going to suck in more ways than just set literals not existing. You may be stuck with 2.6 or 2.3 or 2.1, but you're presumably stuck with it. So, either no `str.format` or only half the features; no `with` or single-value-only `with` (and broken `contextlib.nested`), no `io` or slow and broken `io`, no dict and set comps, etc. Even in 2.6, set literals are hardly the biggest thing you'll miss.

Comment: @abarnert: wow, that's not at all how I read you.  On the bright side, I think that's elliptical enough that I don't feel particularly bad for not having picked up on it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `in` operator:

```
if x in range(1, 5)
```

On Python2 you can use `xrange`.

On Python 3.2+ it is recommended to use set literals:

`if x in {1, 2, 3, 4}`:

[From docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations):

> Python’s peephole optimizer now recognizes patterns such x`in {1, 2,
>   3}` as being a test for membership in a set of constants. The optimizer
>   recasts the `set` as a `frozenset` and stores the pre-built constant.
>   Now that the speed penalty is gone, it is practical to start writing
>   membership tests using set-notation. This style is both semantically
>   clear and operationally fast.

Comment: This is a good solution for Python 3, but the OP is using Python 2, which means it will have to create a list and then search it linearly. Not a horrible problem for only 4 values, but for only 4 values I don't think it's more concise or readable than just writing `[1, 2 ,3, 4]`.

Comment: For Python 2, just use `xrange` instead.

Comment: @chepner: I don't think it's documented anywhere that `in` on an `xrange` is constant time in 2.x.

Comment: In fact, it _isn't_ constant time in 2.7; try `%timeit 10000 in xrange(20000)`, `%timeit 100000 in xrange(200000)`, `%timeit 1000000 in xrange(2000000)` and it's clearly linear.

Comment: Anyway, for a range with a default `step` and integer values, you can just write `1 <= x < 5`…

Comment: OK, I thought I remembered reading once that `in` on `xrange` objects just tested the bounds (which, come to think of it, would be incorrect for a discrete set of values).

Comment: @chepner: Nope, that's a change made in 3.x (I forget when) and not backported to 2.x.

Comment: Your last edit seems more relevant to kindall's answer (and my and his comments underneath it) than to your answer, unless you actually show using a set.

Comment: I think a better way to put this is: In Python 3.2+, use set literals for a short list of static values, use range objects for a larger or more dynamic range; in older versions, upgrade to 3.2+, rewrite the check (e.g., as `1 <= x < 5`), or use set literals but just know they won't be as efficient as in 3.2+.

Comment: I believe you can also do `if in` for list comprehensions - is that correct?

Comment: @HawkWeisman You mean something like: `if 2 in [x for x in (1,2,3,4)]`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: yeah - I haven't actually tried it but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @HawkWeisman Yes, this works fine. But, in case the list is large then it's better to [use a generator expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11963722/846892).

Answer (score 0):

```
if x>=1 or x<=4:
```

will do the job

Comment: Python allows the even shorter `if 1 <= x <= 4`, which also implies `and` (as DSM points out).

Comment: What if `x==10`?  (IOW, I think you mean `and`.)  But this would also let `x==1.5` pass too.

Comment: I'd actually prefer `if 0 < x < 5` for that type of comparison.

Comment: the (1,2,3,4) was just made up numbers; pretend like it's (1, 17, 3, 10000,4) or something.  Sorry for being unclear about that, but the "if x in (1,17,3,10000,4)" is the ideal method I was looking for.  Thanks, though!