# Finding a name in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have code that finds the input name in a CSV if it is present it says yes else no. But I entered a name present in the CSV yet it still says no.

Here is the code:

```
import csv

f=open("student.csv","r")
reader=csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print
studentToFind = raw_input("Enter the name of sudent?")
if studentToFind in reader:
        print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply ask the question before you loop over the file:

```
import csv

studentToFind = raw_input("Enter the name of student?")

f=open("student.csv","r")
reader=csv.reader(f)
found = "No"
for row in reader:
    if studentToFind in row:
        found = "Yes"

f.close()

print('{}'.format(found))
```

Comment: it works if i enter the name that is not present "NO". But when i enter the name that is present in the csv then output is both "Yes" "NO"

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple of issues:

First `reader` is empty at this point, since you've already looped over its elements. Reading from a [file](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) is a one-time deal, if you want to access its contents more than once you need to write it to a data structure, e.g.:

```
rows = []
with open("student.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    rows.append(row)
```

However this also won't be sufficient, because `rows` is now a 2D list, as each [`row` the reader returns](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is itself a list. An [easy way to search for a value in nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11963711/113632) is with list comprehensions:

```
if studentToFind in [cell for row in rows for cell in row]:
  print('yes')
else:
  print('no')
```

---

Put it together, so the indentation's easier to see:

```
rows = []
with open("student.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    rows.append(row)

if studentToFind in [cell for row in rows for cell in row]:
  print('yes')
else:
  print('no')
```

Comment: It gives output 4 times'

Comment: Notice the `if` statement is not inside the `with` statement. You read the file, close it, *then* search `rows`.

Comment: break is working but it is also printing NO after yes when the entered name is found

Comment: Yep, my first comment was wrong; you should not be calling the `if` statement inside the loop. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You've already iterated over the file once. When you try to loop over `reader` again there is nothing to loop over.

Instead don't even use the `csv` module and save the lines in the file into a list:

```
with open("student.csv","r") as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

studentToFind = raw_input("Enter the name of student?")
if studentToFind in lines:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```