# Python how to check if input string is inside of outer nested string?

Tags: python, list, nested

```
# ******************************************************************************************************
# Data is imported from the included awards_data.py file. Both files must remain in the same directory.
# Do not modify the code in this section.
# You may not hardcode (manually enter in the code) any other data.
from awards_data import SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP
award_list_names = ['sag', 'oscars', 'nbr', 'isa', 'glaad', 'naacp']
award_list_options = [SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP]
# ******************************************************************************************************
```

Program has to ask what list you want to print from the list of lists (this)

```
award_list_options = [SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP]
```

so if the user inputs sag, it should print the values of SAG from the original list of SAG which was imported before

this is the awards_data file if it is relevant

```
SAG = ["1", "2"]

oscars = ["1", "3", "4", "5", "3", 
          "1", "6", "7", "3", "8",
          "1", "32", "3", "2"]

NBR = ["2", "9", "3", "10", "Close", "Sr.", "6"]

ISA = ["1", "11", "12", "1", "13", "Tár", "1"]

GLAAD = ["15", "16", "17", "18", "19"]

NAACP = ["8", "20", "16", "21", "22"]
```

for input sag the output should be:

```
1,2
```

for input oscars, OSCARS, oscarS or with whitespace should be

```
1,3,4,5,3,1,6,7,3,8,1,32,3,2 all separated with new line
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to search nested lists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963711/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-search-nested-lists-in-python)

Comment: @Daviid No it doesn't, because I am not looking for the lists individual values first but I am looking for when/if the string input is inside of the group of lists (award_list_options) and then when it does match I would like to print all the values inside of that matching list name

Comment: Actually in your code you just print('asd') not all the values inside of that matching list name.

Comment: Yes I tried printing asd first instead of the values, to make it easier for now. But it has yet to work so I couldn't progress. asd is just a placeholder for now. But yes, how can I do both?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of errors in your code, you're either not posting you code as you have it, which makes any help we give you useless because we're not on the same page, or you're just ignoring the interpeter errors.

- First of all, you pass nothing to `print_award_winners` so fix that.
- Second, in `Award_Selection.(lower).strip()` `Award_Selection` might be picked up as global variable, it's still best to use arguments for this, also, to make a string lowercase it's `'string'.lower()` like with `strip`
- Lastly that `print_award_winners()` call is indented and python will complain, so fix that too.

Here's the cleaned up code.

```
def print_award_winners(winner):
    winner = winner.lower().strip()
    if winner in award_list_options:
        for movie in award_list_options[winner]:
            print(movie)

award_list_options = {
    "sag": ["1", "2"],
    "oscars": ["1", "3", "4", "5", "3", "1", "6", "7", "3", "8", "1", "32", "3", "2"],
    "nbr": ["2", "9", "3", "10", "Close", "Sr.", "6"],
    "isa": ["1", "11", "12", "1", "13", "Tár", "1"],
    "glaad": ["15", "16", "17", "18", "19"],
    "naacp": ["8", "20", "16", "21", "22"],
}


Award_Selection = input("Enter winner: ")
print_award_winners(Award_Selection)
```

Latest Code:

```
# ******************************************************************************************************
# Data is imported from the included awards_data.py file. Both files must remain in the same directory.
# Do not modify the code in this section.
# You may not hardcode (manually enter in the code) any other data.
from awards_data import SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP
award_list_names = ['sag', 'oscars', 'nbr', 'isa', 'glaad', 'naacp']
award_list_options = [SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP]
# ******************************************************************************************************


def print_award_winners(winner):
    winner = winner.lower().strip()
    if winner in name_to_list_relations:
        for movie in name_to_list_relations[winner]:
            print(movie)

name_to_list_relations = dict(zip(award_list_names, award_list_options))


Award_Selection = input("Enter winner: ")
print_award_winners(Award_Selection)
```

Learn about zip() [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)

Comment: It still doesn't seem to give me any values using this code. This is only a part of the code and can't post the whole code since this is a school project and don't want to post my whole project here due to Academic Misconduct. Although I did post everything needed here.

Comment: If you have values like "Close" and "Sr." with upper case letters then you shouldn´t do `.lower()` because it'll never match those, unless you also want to `lower` every element in the sublists.

Comment: That's why I would want to somehow match sag to SAG and just print SAG as a whole.
so the input can be sag, but it should know it meant SAG and prints everything inside SAG I don't know If I did explain it correctly

Comment: Problem is that I cannot match sag into SAG I can make it .upper() but then oscars list would not work since that is lower case

Comment: It can be done, but it's ugly af code using `eval()` and since you said this is a school project it's obviously not the answer, you've misunderstood the assignment clearly.

Comment: @nhiteking You can't print `SAG` unless you use a dictionary to store all the data. The variable names are _just_ names and not printable text.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I've understood the assignment clearly, here is the rubric:
Menu option 2: If the user selects 2, they should then be asked to choose from a list of awards organizations
As long as the organization acronym is spelled correctly, your program should accept any combination of letter cases and leading/trailing whitespace (e.g. both "Oscars" and "    osCarS    " should be valid
You do not need to consider extra whitespace in the middle of the string
Your program should then print all of the winning movies chosen by that organization, with each title on a new line

Comment: Then, like Peter said you have to use a dictionary to match text with lists.

Comment: @Peter the program has to ask which award list you would like to print basically. if entered sag it would match it with SAG inside this and print the original SAG list from the imported code

from awards_data import SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP

award_list_options = [SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP]

Comment: @Daviid and how can I do that? It is 5 am and I am completely lost
I just edited the original question with an easier question and made myself more clear, sorry about the confusion

Comment: Updated the answer with the correct code, you enter the name of the list and it searches in a dictionary that matches the name with the correct list., then print everything inside that list

Comment: Giving you a vote on this for answering the question like 3 times lol. Anyway @nhiteking you can see how to use dicts now, so you should be able to use the knowledge to complete the rest of your assignment.

Comment: @Daviid problem is, we aren't allowed to change the first two lines of code. so these has to stay as is 

# Do not modify the code in this section.
# You may not hardcode (manually enter in the code) any other data.
from awards_data import SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP
award_list_names = ['sag', 'oscars', 'nbr', 'isa', 'glaad', 'naacp']
award_list_options = [SAG, oscars, NBR, ISA, GLAAD, NAACP]

Comment: Let's start by actually posting the full code so we're not working under false assumptions.

Comment: If possible edit the main question and clean up a bit, remove anything unnecessary and post the question with all requirements, I know you're worried about Academic Misconduct but ypu've already posted a lot so... at least you'll leave understanding how to solve the problem

Comment: Just edited the whole question. Made it more clear

Comment: Updated the answer, I think `name_to_list_relations = dict(zip(award_list_names, award_list_options))` is not in contradiction with *not hardcode (manually enter in the code) any other data*

Comment: YES! the last code worked thank you very much

Comment: Edited again just in case someone saw the miss-edit where I deleted the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example with using a dictionary, not sure if it matches what your "assignment" wants but it should answer your original question.

```
import awards_data

award_list_options = {
    "SAG": awards_data.SAG,
    "oscars": awards_data.oscars,
    "NBR": awards_data.NBR,
    "ISA": awards_data.ISA,
    "GLAAD": awards_data.GLAAD,
    "NAACP": awards_data.NAACP
}


def print_award_winners(winner):
    for award, options in award_list_options.items():
        if winner.lower().strip() in map(str.lower, options):
            print(award)

print_award_winners('1')
# SAG
# oscars
# ISA
```

Not quite sure how they expect you to print out "SAG" from the variable `SAG` but it works if you just hardcode the options. Maybe they just meant for you to learn if statements (ie. `if '1' in SAG: print('SAG')`).

Comment: We arent allowed to change award_list_options list

Comment: Updated to not change it, but yeah it doesn't sound like a "good" assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You need an auxiliary data structure

```
names = [n.lower() for n in ["SAG", "oscars", "NBR", "ISA", "GLAAD", "NAACP"]]
```

then

```
def p():
    s = input('Prompt: ')).lower().strip()
    if s in names:
        print(*award_list_options[names.index(s)] sep=', ')
    else:
        print('No Matches')
```

Even better, use a dictionary.